# How do I recode variables dependent on another variable in spss

Tags: if-statement, syntax, spss

when recoding variables, the dependency on another variable is apparently ignored.

My syntax:

```
if(leaFi15 = '1,2')
 RECODE  f13_1 f13_3 f13_5 f13_2 f13_6 f13_4 f13_7 f13_8 f13_9 f13_10 f13_11 f13_12 f13_13 f13_14 f13_15 (0 = SYSMIS).
EXECUTE.
```

Also by using a numeric variable the same behavior without any error message.

```
if(SYSMIS(f18n))
 RECODE  f13_1 f13_3 f13_5 f13_2 f13_6 f13_4 f13_7 f13_8 f13_9 f13_10 f13_11 f13_12 f13_13 f13_14 f13_15
 (0 = SYSMIS).
EXECUTE.
```

[image: The data before:]

After processing with the syntax:

[image]

Everything is completely deleted in the variables(f13_...) with the value 0. However, only the lines should be changed for which the variable leaFi15 has sysmis. What is wrong with the script here?

I tested the syntax in PSPPIRE, but I guess it should be the same in IBM's SPSS program in this case.

Answer (score 1):

what you are after is `DO IF`, and also how you write the logical condition depends on whether `leaFi15`  is string or numerical:

Assuming it is numerical:

```
DO IF any(leaFi15, 1,2).
 RECODE  f13_1 f13_3 f13_5 f13_2 f13_6 f13_4 f13_7 f13_8 f13_9 f13_10 f13_11 f13_12 f13_13 f13_14 f13_15 (0 = SYSMIS).
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

(this will replace all your 0 values with blanks).

Assuming `leaFi15`  is string, you need to place *each* value between quotation signs:

```
    DO IF any(leaFi15, "1","2").
...
```

Using `DO IF` allows you to place several transformation commands between `DO IF` and `END IF`. A simple `IF` statement only allows for one such transformation.

Comment: Just to make clear, as @horace_vr says you can only put one transformation after an `if` - but regretfully `recode` doesn't count as "one command" in this respect, and has to be enclosed in a `do if` - `end if.` sequence if you want to make it conditional.